# If $\zeta$ is an $n$th roots of unity which is also a $d$th root of unity for smaller $d$, then $d$ divides $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that if $\zeta$ is an $n$th roots of unity which is also a $d$th root of unity for smaller $d$, then $d$ divides $n$.

Given $d < n$, we have $\zeta^n = 1$ and $\zeta^d = 1$, how do I prove that $d$ must divides $n$?

I found this statement from the book abstract algebra written by Dummit and Foote in the section 13. 6 page 552. As some comments pointed out, this statement is clearly false. So I assume I must misunderstood author's meaning. Can someone clarify this for me please?

Comment: $1$ is an $n-$th root of unity for any $n$.

Comment: You can't: take $\zeta=1, n=3,d=2$, or $\zeta=-1, n=6,d=4$ for a less trivial example.

Comment: The best you can say is $\zeta^{\gcd(n,d)}=1$.

Comment: Not true in general. Assume $\zeta^3=1$. Then we have $\zeta^6=\zeta^9=1$ , but $6\nmid 9$

Comment: If $\zeta^n=1$ and $d$ is the smallest positive integer with $\zeta^d=1$, then we in fact must have $d\mid n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is on page 12 of the [current errata](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/%7Erfoote/errata_3rd_edition.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The exact statement in the book is

> if $\zeta$ is an
> $n$th root of unity which is also a $d$th root of unity for some smaller $d$ then $d \mid n$.

This is incorrect. The correct statement is

> if $\zeta$ is an
> $n$th root of unity which is also a *primitive* $d$th root of unity for some smaller $d$ then $d \mid n$.

This interpretation is consistent with the previous sentence

> Conversely, the order of any element of the group $\mu_n$ is a divisor of $n$